# Right align and center align TextView without layout_width="wrap_content"

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, right-align

I need to right-align a textview, but because I'm using `layout_weight`, I need to set `layout_width="0dip"`. Setting `layout_width="wrap_content"` breaks my layout.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
            android:layout_weight="0.95"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:text="name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:text="=" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.95"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:text="value" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The intent is to have a name-value pair aligned to the center of the row, like this:
[image: name-value pair]

All my searching has only yielded the solution to set layout_width="wrap_content", which won't work here.
Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post a screen shot of current output?

Comment: Make parent `LinearLayout` width `fill_parent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your full **xml:**

Just update Main `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.95"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:text="name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:text="=" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.95"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:text="value" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Output is:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Setting the parent LinearLayout layout_width="fill_parent" did the trick.